# How to pass location and radius in google map API?

Tags: google-maps

My goal is to get list of zip codes by passing parameter of location and radius of particular limit.

I got only the location, but I couldn't get the radius of certain zipcode.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=7034&key=YOUR_API_KEY

How can I get the list of zipcode in certain radius ?

Please guide me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need a database that contains data about the zipcodes.  Here is an example that uses a FusionTable containing US zip codes:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcodeInRadius.html

**code snippet:**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
});
var map;
var labels = [];
var layer;
var tableid = "1VFp4XJEdnR769R2CFRghlmDpUd15dQArpwzcBBs"; //1499916;
var circle;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.23032838760389, -118.65234375),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      from: tableid,
      select: "geometry"
    }
  });
  // layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry' FROM " + tableid);
  layer.setMap(map);

  codeAddress();

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      if (results[0].geometry.viewport)
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

      var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
      var radius = parseFloat(document.getElementById('radius').value) * 1609.34;
      if (isNaN(radius)) radius = 5 * 1609.34; // default to 5 miles
      displayZips(results[0].geometry.location, radius);
      if (circle && circle.setMap) {
        circle.setMap(null);
      }
      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: latLng,
        radius: radius,
        map: map
      });
      layer.setQuery({
        select: 'geometry',
        from: tableid,
        where: "ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + latLng.toUrlValue(6) + ")," + radius.toFixed(2) + "))"
      });

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function displayZips(latLng, radius) {
  var queryStr = "SELECT geometry, ZIP, latitude, longitude FROM " + tableid + " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + latLng.toUrlValue(6) + ")," + radius.toFixed(2) + "))";
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(queryStr);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(displayZipText);

}


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function displayZipText(response) {
  if (!response) {
    alert('no response');
    return;
  }
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  if (map.getZoom() < 11) return;
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
  var zipsList = "";
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var zip = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1);
    var zipStr = zip.toString()
    while (zipStr.length < 5) {
      zipStr = '0' + zipStr;
    }
    zipsList += zipStr + " ";
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2)),
      parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3)));
  }
  document.getElementById('zips').innerHTML = "zipcodes in radius=" + zipsList;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<form>
  <span class="style51"><span class="style49">Show</span>:</span>
  <label>Address:</label><input id="address" type="text" value="07646" /><label>Radius:</label><input id="radius" type="text" value="0.5" />
  <input id="geocode" type="button" onclick="codeAddress();" value="Geocode" />
</form>
<div id="zips"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I dont really want to connect with database. I just want to display the zipcode only. Is there any method to achieve without connecting the database.